# Suddenly I can't deploy Terraform in GCP: unknown project id mentioned (681255809395)

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I had a working terraform deployment on GCP (using google provider 5.7.0).
Suddenly, my deployment stopped working and an unknown project (681255809395) is mentioned:

```
 Error: Error creating Config: googleapi: Error 403: BigQuery Data Transfer API has not been used in project 681255809395 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/overview?project=681255809395 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
│     "links": [
│       {
│         "description": "Google developers console API activation",
│         "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/overview?project=681255809395"
│       }
│     ]
│   },
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/681255809395",
│       "service": "bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
│ ]
│
│   with module.bq-scheduled-query-pipedrive-deals.google_bigquery_data_transfer_config.query_config,
│   on modules/bq-scheduled-query/main.tf line 1, in resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config":
│    1: resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config" {
```

This project ID is not my project ID nor belongs to my organization. I've googled the project ID and I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395410/google-cloud-terraform-gcloud-problem-with-google-service-networking-connecti) mentioning a similar problem WITH THE SAME PROJECT ID.

The relevant part in TF log is the following:

```
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: 2023/11/23 10:54:36 [INFO] Instantiating Google Cloud Billing client for path https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: 2023/11/23 10:54:36 [DEBUG] Retry Transport: starting RoundTrip retry loop
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: 2023/11/23 10:54:36 [DEBUG] Retry Transport: request attempt 0
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: 2023/11/23 10:54:36 [DEBUG] Google API Request Details:
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: ---[ REQUEST ]---------------------------------------
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: GET /v1/projects/CORRECT_PROJECT_NAME_HERE/billingInfo?alt=json&prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Host: cloudbilling.googleapis.com
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: User-Agent: google-api-go-client/0.5 Terraform/1.6.4 (+https://www.terraform.io) Terraform-Plugin-SDK/2.10.1 terraform-provider-google/5.7.0
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: X-Goog-Api-Client: gl-go/1.19.9 gdcl/0.148.0
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5
2023-11-23T10:54:36.297-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: 2023/11/23 10:54:36 [DEBUG] Google API Response Details:
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: HTTP/2.0 403 Forbidden
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Cache-Control: private
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Date: Thu, 23 Nov 2023 13:54:36 GMT
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Server: ESF
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Vary: Origin
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Vary: X-Origin
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: Vary: Referer
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: X-Xss-Protection: 0
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5: {
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:   "error": {
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:     "code": 403,
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:     "message": "Cloud Billing API has not been used in project 681255809395 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudbilling.googleapis.com/overview?project=681255809395 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:     "errors": [
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:       {
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:         "message": "Cloud Billing API has not been used in project 681255809395 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudbilling.googleapis.com/overview?project=681255809395 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:         "domain": "usageLimits",
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:         "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:         "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:       }
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:     ],
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:     "details": [
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:       {
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:         "links": [
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:           {
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:             "description": "Google developers console API activation",
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:             "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudbilling.googleapis.com/overview?project=681255809395"
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:           }
2023-11-23T10:54:36.416-0300 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-google_v5.7.0_x5:         ]
```

If I click on that link to enable cloudbilling (and add authuser=1 to the URL) I get a permission denied error:

```
You need additional access
You need additional access to the project:  681255809395
To request access, contact your project administrator and provide them a copy of the following information:

Troubleshooting info:
  Principal: martin@retcousa.com
  Resource: 681255809395
  Troubleshooting URL: console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/troubleshooter;permissions=resourcemanager.projects.get;principal=martin@retcousa.com;resources=%2F%2Fcloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com%2Fprojects%2F681255809395/result

Missing permissions:
  resourcemanager.projects.get
```

I'm completely puzzled here, what is this project ID?

Note: if you google for the project ID number, you'll see the first result is a google cloud URL so evidently it's linked from other public documents.

Comment: Have you tried creating a support ticket with the Google Cloud support team?